# Is there a way to permanently set \bf to \textbf in .bbl

Tags: bibliographies, bold, bbl

Is there a way to permanently set `\bf` to `\textbf`? The .bbl file I use uses \bf which leads to errors and me having to reset every entry manually to \textbf. Each time I add a new citation, each time the .bbl file changes, I have to redo everything, otherwise I can't continue working. For example the following:

```
\harvarditem{Wurm}{2004}{Wurm2004}
Wurm, F.~M.  \harvardyearleft 2004\harvardyearright , `{Production of
  recombinant protein therapeutics in cultivated mammalian cells}', {\em Nature
  Biotechnology} {\bf 22}(11),~393--398.
\newline\harvardurl{https://doi.org/10.1038/nbt1026}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliography{Mendeley}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Also, which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the syntax of `\bf` and `\textbf` are different, it would be better to make `\bf` be `\bfseries` which you can do via

```
\renewcommand\bf{\bfseries}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Just one follow up question. How exactly doe they differ in their syntax? I thought both could be used to make text bold and \bf was simply older/from an older package.

Comment: \bf is a declaration which charges the state within the enclosing group while \texbf is a command which takes an argument and sets it in bold.

Comment: @Han look at the example you posted: `{\bf 22}` makes **22** but `{\textbf 22}` would be the same as `{\textbf{2}2}` and make **2**2

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that get the error because you are using one of the KOMA classes, you can add definitions for the old font commands by copying them from e.g. article.cls:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the `agsm` bibliography style, another way to achieve your objective is to modify this bibliography style so that it uses `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`. Fortunately, this is easy to do. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `agsm-bfseries.bst`. (You are obviously free to choose a different, presumably easier, file name.)
- Open the file `agsm-bfseries.bst` in a text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Inside `agsm-bfseries.bst`, locate the function called `embolden`. It should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {embolden}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  ```

  In this function, change `\bf` to `\bfseries`. (Yes, that's really all that has to be changed!)
- Save the file `agsm-bfseries.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as well.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsm-bfseries}
  ```

  Then, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!