# Undefined old font command \sc in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, koma-script, scrbook, undefined

got an issue with latex in the bibliography. Im using this template I got from my university (yeah its old and stuff but thats not the point, we have to use it no matter what...).

Template:

```
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Diplomarbeit mit LaTeX
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright, DIV15, BCOR15mm]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=empty}
%
% Packages
\usepackage{hanser}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
% Hyperref-Optionen für PDF-Files
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% Verhindert Schusterjungen und Hurenkinder
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000
%
% Kein Einzug beim Paragraphenanfang
\parindent0.0cm
\parskip1.5ex
% Stil für das Literaturverzeichnis
\bibliographystyle{geralpha}
% Tiefe für das Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
% listings-Package
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%   Hintergrundfarbe von Quellcode
\definecolor{codecolor}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\lstloadlanguages{[ANSI]C++, Java}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily \small}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{codecolor}}
\lstset{extendedchars=true} \lstset{showstringspaces = false}
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
%
% Kopfzeile
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[L, RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \nouppercase  \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %
}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Abstände zwischen Caption und Bild/Tabelle
\setlength\abovecaptionskip          {0.4em}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip          {0.2em}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {titel},
    pdfauthor = {author},
    pdfsubject = {Praxisarbeit},
    pdfkeywords = {Praxisarbeit Fachhochschule Kaiserslautern},
    pdfdisplaydoctitle = true,
    pdfpagelayout = {SinglePage}
}
% Anteil der Grafiken höher auf jeder Seite!
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.99}

\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\small \bfseries}

% Kein Auseinanderziehen gegen das Seitenende
\raggedbottom
%
% Beginn Dokument
%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{titel}
\date{date}
\author{author}
\maketitle
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
% Schalten Sie auf kleine römische Zahlen als Nummerierung um -- sonst
% fängt im Inhaltsverzeichnis das erste Kapitel auf Seite 6 an; Seite 1 wäre besser, oder?
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
% Jetzt schalten wir wieder auf arabische Zahlen, und die Zähler werden zurückgesetzt
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%Input aller Teildateien
\input{content/einleitung}
\input{content/orbis}
\input{content/motivation}
\input{content/itil}
\input{content/jiraproducts}
\input{content/server_vs_cloud}
\input{content/configuration}
\input{content/zusammenfassung}

% Literatur
\chaptermark{Literaturverzeichnis}
\sectionmark{Literaturverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{main}

% Anhang
\appendix

\input{content/ehren}
%\input{content/sperre}

\end{document}
```

This is how I included the literature I used in the .bib file:

```
@book{itil_kompakt,
    author = {Alfred Olbrich},
    year = {2006},
    title = {ITIL kompakt und verst{\"a}ndlich},
    publisher = {vieweg}
}
```

And this is the "output" I get in the .bbl file (which latex automatically generates as far as I know):

```
\bibitem[Olb06]{itil_kompakt}
{\sc Olbrich, Alfred}: {\em ITIL kompakt und verst{\"a}ndlich}.
\newblock vieweg, 2006.
```

Problem with that now is, everytime I compile I get the following error for every item I add to the .bib file:

```
Class scrbook Error: Undefined old font command \sc
```

But I get the error shown in the .bbl file, in which I dont even write anything (cause thats automatically generated isnt it?)

Now how can I fix this error?

Comment: The form of the `bbl` file is controlled by the style loaded with the `\bibliographystyle` command, in this case `geralpha.bst`. Under CTAN this is listed under "obsolete". I'd suggest to use a less obsolete style `:-)`

Comment: Define the font commands https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385466/2388 or use the class option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands`.